# How to convert a datetime-String with a comma (,) in the milliseconds part in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, string-conversion

I got the following problem:

The date-time columns from my data got the following time-format (the columns are "Date" `dd.mm.yyyy` and "Time" `hh:mm:ss.fff,f`):

```
01.03.2019  12:29:15.732,7
```

I looked around but I couldn't find a formatting-option which deals with the part behind the comma (after the milliseconds).
A source which didn't help me:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

I am reading the csv-file in with python3 and `pd.read_csv()`.

I got the following work-around which truncates the comma and the cipher behind it.

It is terribly slow because of the truncation of over 50000 strings in my dataset:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv', sep=';', low_memory = False, parse_dates = [['Date', 'Time']], 
                   date_parser = lambda x, y : pd.to_datetime((x + ' ' + y)[:23], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

What I want is to use a string-formatting which deals with the comma, either by discarding the whole milliseconds part or by converting it correctly to microseconds.

Sidenote: With R I simply used `"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"` which discarded the milliseconds without throwing an error.

Comment: Can you try `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.replace(',', ''))`? Remove `,` first then convert it to `datetime`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I guess this is one way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResidentSleeper is correct you can use `pd.to_datetime()` and drop the comma.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Date': ['01.03.2019  12:29:15.732,7',
                  '01.03.2019  12:29:15.732,7',
                  '01.03.2019  12:29:15.732,7',
                  '01.03.2019  12:29:15.732,7'], 
        'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'].str.replace(',', ''))

print(df1)

                        Date  Value
0 2019-01-03 12:29:15.732700      1
1 2019-01-03 12:29:15.732700      2
2 2019-01-03 12:29:15.732700      3
3 2019-01-03 12:29:15.732700      4
```

Comment: Yes, I guess this is one way of doing it and that there is no easier way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If a number of columns with dates formatted having one or more commas, you can eliminate commas using `DataFrame.replace`, with the regex option set to True:

```
     data = {'Date1': ['01.03.2019  12:29:15.732,7',
                  '01.03.2019  12:29:15.732,7',
                  '01.03.2019  12:29:15.732,7',
                  '01.03.2019  12:29:15.732,7'], 
              'Date2': ['01.04.2019  12:30:005.732,7',
                  '01.04.2019  12:31:15.732,7',
                  '01.04.2019  12:32:35.732,7',
                  '01.04.2019  12:33:45.732,7'], 
        Value': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1 = df1[['Date1','Date2']].replace(',', '', regex=True).applymap(pd.to_datetime)

print(df1)
                       Date1                      Date2
0 2019-01-03 12:29:15.732700 2019-01-04 12:30:05.732700
1 2019-01-03 12:29:15.732700 2019-01-04 12:31:15.732700
2 2019-01-03 12:29:15.732700 2019-01-04 12:32:35.732700
3 2019-01-03 12:29:15.732700 2019-01-04 12:33:45.732700


df1.dtypes
Date1    datetime64[ns]
Date2    datetime64[ns]
```